# Вывод сгенерированных файлов с исходным текстом.К файлу JAR класса не присоединены исходные файлы

Tags: java, netbeans

В Netbeans хотел посмотреть как внутри устроен HashMap, но при переходе в класс, отсутствуют тела методов, вместо них "// compiled code". а сверху окна "Вывод сгенерированных файлов с исходным текстом.К файлу JAR класса не присоединены исходные файлы". Подскажите какие исходники он требует, как их подключить? После подключения исходников будут ли отображаться тела методов?

Comment: [Исходники класса HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) хочет. Скачайте исходный код [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) и смотрите. Только расстрою вас, в стандартной библиотеке java-код часто используется только как fallback при невозможности использовать платформозависимый код на C++.

Comment: А у JDK от Oracle исходный код лежит в корне каталога установки в виде архива src.zip.